# Google Maps Info Window is smaller since last night

Tags: google-maps, dictionary, infowindow

Google just changed the way that the info window appears. It is smaller and it displays a vertical scrollbar, like in their demo: http://code.google.com/apis/ajax/playground/#info_windows_complex_v3

Did Google announced anywhere this change? Any idea how to fix it (to make the info window automatically adjust its height based on its content - as it was until last night)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yesterday version 3.14 has been released where [google.maps.visualRefresh](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#VisualRefresh) is set to `true` by default, what causes infoWindows to look different than in previous versions.

3.14 is an experimental version, I would suggest to [explicitly set the version](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/basics#Versioning) of the  used API to the release-version 3.13 and wait if there will be any options available in the future(currently there is no option documented).

Comment: Thank you for such a documented answer! I was using http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false&v=3.exp call to their API. Replacing the version parameter from v=3.exp to v=3 to point to the stable release indeed shows now correctly the classic info window.